# Execution Efficiency vs Programmer Efficiency in R

Tags: performance, r

The classic and brilliant Programming Perl reference book has a section in which the authors provide a list of advice for how to write Perl that is maximally *computationally efficient*, followed by a list of advice for how to write Perl that is maximally *programmer efficient*, followed by more advice for *maintainer efficient*, *porter efficient*, and *user efficient*. The advice is usually completely contradictory. (E.g., "use globals", "don't use globals.")

I thought of this while working on turning some "programmer efficient" R code into "computationally and maintainer efficient" code.

What are some interesting and useful tips for R style along these lines? What practices are maximally programmer efficient, and what are the equivalent practices that address other notions of efficiency?

Comment: Remember users will only care about how fast the application works, not how fast you can build or maintain it, This seems to be lost the last few years as people seem to think programmer efficiency trumps everything. Believe me, it doesn't to users. If the advice is contradictory, go with the advice that is most likly to produce efficently performing code not what will be quickest to write.

Comment: @HLGEM:  Users also care about getting the application fast, and what it costs them, and sometimes how fast it can be modified to what they want.  For most apps, computational inefficiency is irrelevant.  Even for R-type apps, computational power is increasing far faster than programmer productivity, and so the balance point shifts ever farther towards valuing programmer productivity.

Comment: I think @HLGEM's comment is very appropriate for desktop or web apps that are general purpose and wide audience. Much of what is written in R, however, is domain specific and used as part of an analyst's workbench. I suspect this different use case fundamentally changes the marginal value calculation.

Comment: @JD:  For most desktop and web apps, computational efficiency isn't that important.  The app performance will usually be limited by other things.  There are exceptions, of course, but programming for maximum computational efficiency is usually the wrong thing to do.  R, on the other hand, is typically used for numeric purposes, where computational efficiency will matter.  It's also true, as you point out, that R programs tend to be more specialized, so programming time can't be amortized like a shrink-wrap product.  The trade-offs are similar but the factors going into them are different.

Answer (score 20):

> ```
> Programmer efficient                 |   Computationally efficient
>                                      |
> Write everything in R                |   Call C/Fortran routines
> Reuse code                           |   Custom create everything 
>   (functions not scripts,            |
>   packages not individual functions) |
> Use high level functions             |   Use low-level functions
> Write things that work               |   Write it, profile it, optimise it.
>                                      |     Repeat ad infinitum.
> ```

Comment: Would love to see some more examples like this, especially with more details!

Answer (score 2):

What you can count on being slow is anything that, in a loop, rebuilds data, like appending elements to a vector, *if it is done a lot*.

Answer (score 1):

I think style guidelines (as discussed before on SO) help for programmer efficiency.  R Core seems to agree by providing some hints (and Emacs parameters for consistent indenting).

Execution efficiency is more difficult to achieve by decree. You may have to fall back to rules of thumb ('vectorise') as well as profiling.